# Calculate spherical Terrain Normals from HeightMap

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, perlin-noise

I try to calculate the Vertex Normal from HeightMap Values.
I create a HeightMap at the beginning. This works so far. LOD works too.

I know how to calculate Normals for flat Terrain but how can i do this for spherical Terrain?
[image]
As you can see the Lighting is not working and NormalMaps dont work too.

I was thinking about to first calculate the Normals and Tangents as it would be flat Terrain. And than use some Transformation so the Normals and Tangents 
fit the spherical Terrrain.

**Edit 1:**
Thats what i got so far. Is this correct Michael Nastenko? Here i use PerlinNoise not the Heightmap

```
float x1 = pRadius * FMath::Cos(lat + yDelta) * FMath::Cos(lon);
float y1 = pRadius * FMath::Cos(lat + yDelta) * FMath::Sin(lon);
float z1 = pRadius * FMath::Sin(lat + yDelta);

float x2 = pRadius * FMath::Cos(lat - yDelta) * FMath::Cos(lon);
float y2 = pRadius * FMath::Cos(lat - yDelta) * FMath::Sin(lon);
float z2 = pRadius * FMath::Sin(lat - yDelta);

float x3 = pRadius * FMath::Cos(lat) * FMath::Cos(lon + xDelta);
float y3 = pRadius * FMath::Cos(lat) * FMath::Sin(lon + xDelta);
float z3 = pRadius * FMath::Sin(lat);

float x4 = pRadius * FMath::Cos(lat) * FMath::Cos(lon - xDelta);
float y4 = pRadius * FMath::Cos(lat) * FMath::Sin(lon - xDelta);
float z4 = pRadius * FMath::Sin(lat);


float xDifference = GetNoiseValue(FVector(x1, y1, z1).GetSafeNormal())
    - GetNoiseValue(FVector(x2, y2, z2).GetSafeNormal());
float yDifference = GetNoiseValue(FVector(x3, y3, z3).GetSafeNormal())
    - GetNoiseValue(FVector(x4, y4, z4).GetSafeNormal());

FVector planeTangent = FVector(1.f, 0.f, xDifference).GetSafeNormal();
FVector planeBiTangent = FVector(0.f, 1.f, yDifference).GetSafeNormal();
```

**Edit 2:**
x1,y1,z1... are the adjacent points of the Vertex, i want to calculate the Tangent/Normal. For each of those Points i get the NoiseValue. So i can use finite differences to get the slope of the surface.
Shouldn't this be the Way to get the Tangent of flat Terrain?

**Edit 3:**
Calculating Normals like this is somehow wrong.

```
TArray<FVector> normals;
normals.Init(FVector(0, 0, 0), geoData.GeoData.Num());
int32 triangleCount = geoData.Triangles.Num() / 3;
for (int32 i = 0; i < triangleCount; i++)
{
    int32 normalTriangleIndex = i * 3;
    int32 triangleIndexA = geoData.Triangles[normalTriangleIndex];
    int32 triangleIndexB = geoData.Triangles[normalTriangleIndex + 1];
    int32 triangleIndexC = geoData.Triangles[normalTriangleIndex + 2];

    FVector pointA = geoData.GeoData[triangleIndexA];
    FVector pointB = geoData.GeoData[triangleIndexB];
    FVector pointC = geoData.GeoData[triangleIndexC];


    FVector sideAB = pointB - pointA;
    FVector sideAC = pointC - pointA;


    FVector norm;
    norm= FVector::CrossProduct(sideAB, sideAC);


    normals[triangleIndexA] = -norm;
    normals[triangleIndexB] = -norm;
    normals[triangleIndexC] = -norm;
}
geoData.NormalsData = normals;
```

On the left is my calculation, on the right i used the build in function of UE4
[image]

Comment: Well, it's not much different for spherical terrain - for each point calculate world position of point and 4 adjacent points and use them to calculate your tangent space. Show some code, to begin with.

Comment: Tangent plane is key, you know your normal will be perpendicular to that.

Comment: Your way to apply noise doesn't make much sense to me. I'd apply noise value to a radius at each point. But this noise values MUST be stable - each point MUST have the same noise value all the time. And your T/B calculations are completely wrong. It looks like you do not understand they geometrical meaning. Tangent is a world/object stape vector of texture coordinates gradient. Check this link: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68612/how-to-compute-tangent-and-bitangent-vectors

Comment: I am checking your link. i will edit the post asap

Comment: Noise should be applied to z values only. Then `FVector planeTangent = (FVector(x3, y3, z3) - FVector(x4, y4, z4)).GetSafeNormal` (if you UV.x is same as `long`)

Comment: Why should you appy noise to z value only? It's a Sphere

Comment: @NilsJ. Oh, sorry. Not to z, but to `pRadius`

Comment: Ok, so i found the issue. Somehow the Normals you can see in the left Picture pointing up, where from a second Mesh which is a Result of how i add Collision.